Next.js set const to value when a function Form loads
I have a Next.js application that loads a user from a PostgreSQL database. The data loaded are

user_id
user_email
user_display_name
user_avatar_url

I am now buidling a page where the user can edit the Avatar URL. My issue is that I want the variable userAvatarUrl to be user.user_avatar_url when data from /api/users/my-user has loaded.
How can I set the userAvatarUrl after the user data has loaded?
app(private)\account\avatar\edit\page.tsx
"use client";
import Form from "./form";

export default function AvatarEditPage() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Edit Avatar</h1>

      <Form />
      
    </div>
  );
}

app(private)\account\avatar\edit\form.tsx
"use client";

import React, { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

function Form(){
    console.log("app/(private)/account/avatar/edit/form.tsx::Form()::Init");

    // Consts
    const [userAvatarUrl, setUserAvatarUrl] = useState<undefined | string>("");

    // My User
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("/api/users/my-user");
    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (isLoading) return <div>
            <div role="status">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" className="inline w-4 h-4 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-blue-600" viewBox="0 0 100 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                    <path d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z" fill="currentFill"/>
                </svg>
                <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    const user = data.data;

    //  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // HERE I WANT TO SET THE VARIABLE userAvatarUrl to user.user_avatar_url
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Handle submit
    async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent){
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await fetch("/api/avatar/edit", {
            method: "post",
            body: JSON.stringify({userAvatarUrl})
        });
        if (res.ok){
            alert("Ok");
        }
        else{
            alert("Failed");
        }
    }

    // HTML
    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   

            <p>
            <label>Avatar</label><br />
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setUserAvatarUrl(e.target.value)} id="user_avatar_url" placeholder="Avatar URL" required className="text-black p-3 border border-slate-700 rounded-lg" />
            </p>


            <button type="submit" className="mt-4 bg-slate-900 text-white p-3 rounded-lg">Save changes</button>
          

        </form>
    )


}

export default Form;

app\api\users\my-user\route.ts
import { getJWTPayload } from "@/app/util/auth";
import { sql } from "@/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { json } from "stream/consumers";

// My user gives the user data for the current logged in user

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // get currently logged in user
  const jwtPayload = await getJWTPayload();

  // fetch user data
  const res = await sql(
    "SELECT user_id, user_email, user_display_name, user_avatar_url FROM v_users_index WHERE user_id = $1",
    [jwtPayload.sub]
  );
  const user = res.rows[0];

  // return user data
  return NextResponse.json({ data: user });
}

